# Alert notification

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote simple script which is running all the time and whenever the size of a file is changed it will write something like "The size has changed" to terminal but instead of terminal message, is it possible to actually get some prompt or some alert sound like in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you can output the BEL character '\a'. In a script you can do so with:

```
echo -e '\a'
```

If you don't get a sound with that, be sure to check that there is no

```
blacklist pcspkr
```

in your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (and if there is comment it out and reboot).

Alternatively, if you have a nice sound short sound file `xyz.mp3`, and have `vlc` installed, you can do:

```
cvlc --no-one-instance --volume 100 --quiet --no-loop --no-repeat --play-and-exit xyz.mp3
```

Comment: Yeah but it does not make any sound i have already tried it just gives me newline

Comment: You can prevent the newline with `-n` but not getting the BEL to sound looks like a terminal setting problem to me.

Comment: Yeah it may be any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked that your **don't** have `blacklist pcspkr` in your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (if you do comment out and reboot)

Comment: If that still doesn't make a sound, make sure your motherboard has a speaker attached :-)

Comment: That vlc command looks really good i can play whcihever sound i want but it does not work gives me VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
Warning: option --volume no longer exists.
vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `--no-on-instance'
Try `vlc --help' for more information.

Comment: I am not sure what replaced `--volume` I took this from an old script I no longer use, try leaving it out.. The `--no-on-instance` was lacking an `e` that option makes sure you can watch a video and still have the bell ring (in a new instance, hence `--no-one-instance`).

Answer (score 2):

If your terminal does not make any sound, it still (more likely than not) can make a visible alarm:

```
tput flash
```

For most systems, [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) accepts `terminfo` names including `flash`.  The [terminfo](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html) manual for ncurses says:

```
   flash_screen              flash  vb   visible bell (may
                                         not move cursor)
```

and

```
   If the terminal has a way of flashing the screen to  indi-
   cate  an  error quietly (a bell replacement) then this can
   be given as flash; it must not move the cursor.
```

A few implementations accept only termcap names.  Some terminal emulators do not flash the screen using any method (and in ncurses' [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html), the preferred terminal description for those excludes the feature).  Some of those may set `TERM` to `xterm` (but [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) itself works).

Comment: Tried but does not do anything , tried to type tput flash , am i doing anything wrong? and what does flash do? i could not find anything about it in tput manual

Comment: What terminal are you using?  (A few do not support this feature because their VT100 emulation is broken).

Comment: I use xterm terminal

Comment: What does `echo $XTERM_VERSION` show?

Comment: it shows an empty line

Comment: Sounds like you're using something like GNOME-Terminal...